# Какой алгоритм нечеткого поиска лучше для 10 тысяч строк из 50 символов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, нечеткий-поиск

Есть массив из 10000 строк. Средняя длина строки 50 символов.

Символы в строках: `a-я0-9'"%+!& .,;\-()/`

Поиск осуществляется на клиенте при помощи JavaScript. Сейчас использую простой поиск по точному совпадению при помощи метода indexOf. Какой алгоритм будет оптимальнее?

Comment: Что означает "нечёткий"  и каковы критерии оптимальности? Например, если я предложу пройтись стеммером сначала по всем словам массива, потом сформировать хэши, где результаты стемминга будут ключами. Потом обработать стеммером входное слово и проверять наличие результата в хэшах - это будет достаточно нечётко и достаточно оптимально?

Comment: Под нечетким поиском я имел ввиду поиск с учетом опечаток при вводе с русской клавиатуры раскладки "ЙЦУКЕН".

Comment: Выбирайте алгоритм, ищите реализации на JS (некоторые не сложно и самому написать - например, дистанцию Левенштейна), тестируйте... https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/ Всё зависит от входных данных в том числе,  от структуры базы для поиска, от длины слов etc.

Comment: вот, например, рабочий вариант [расстояния Левенштейна на JS](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927)

Answer (score 3):

*Из комментария пользователя [@PinkTux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194908/pink-tux):*

Выбирайте алгоритм, ищите реализации на JS (некоторые не сложно и самому написать — например, дистанцию Левенштейна), тестируйте. Всё зависит от входных данных в том числе, от структуры базы для поиска, от длины слов и так далее.

Можно почитать статью «[Нечёткий поиск в тексте и словаре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114997)».

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема в том, что для каждой ошибки нужен свой алгоритм. Опечатка - наиболее сложный вариант.
С раскладкой могу посоветовать сразу при наборе каждую букву переводить в другую раскладку и сразу осуществлять 2 поиска - на той раскладке что вводят и на изменённой. Если один из вариантов пуст а другой уже нашёл что-то после 3 букв например то можно показывать на экране.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Bitap. Реализации на JS у меня нет, но с C# он списывается почти один в один :)
Вот реализация: [Fuzzy Bitap Algorithm](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/fuzzy-bitap-algorithm?lang=C%23)